# Downsides of using Autobahn as WAMP router?

Tags: websocket, autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar

I'm currently looking into using the WAMP-protocol to synchronise between server and clients of my future web-applications.

They recommend using [crossbar.io as the router](http://autobahn.ws/js/) but since Autobahn supports all four roles (publisher, subscriber, caller, callee) itself I'm wondering why I would need another router framework like crossbar.io at all?

I'd like to use node.js with Autobahn|JS as the router and Autobahn|JS in the web-browser as the client. Is this feasible or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autobahn(JS/Python/CPP) supports all four **client** roles, but since WAMP is a routed protocol, you still need a WAMP router. Autobahn does not provide that, and there's now way in which you could use AutobahnJS to create a WAMP router on Node.js.

The WAMP router is not a framework - it's a component which you configure (authentication, authorization, transports etc.) and then just leave running. When everything is configured properly, this is completely transparent for your application.

I'm part of the Autobahn and Crossbar.io projects - so my recommendation is Crossbar.io, but there are other WAMP routers out there. These differ e.g. in regards to the amount of features they implement and their performance. As long as you don't rely on the features of a particular router, you can swap out the WAMP router at any time.

Comment: If you can subscribe and publish between clients then what is the role of the Router? I'm coming from DDP where client subscribe to the server but it seems to be different here.

Comment: WAMP has 6 roles: 4 client roles (caller, callee, publisher, subscriber) and 2 router roles (dealer and broker). A publisher can't talk to subscribers directly, but needs a broker in between. Similar with caller, callee and dealer.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @oberstet
So what I want is a node server that is dealer, broker, callee and publisher at once. Both node.js router options nightlife-rabbit and wamp-rt look a bit neglected and I don't want to use crossbar.io. Are there better maintained router-options?

Comment: I am using Crossbar.io, unsurprisingly;) Also combined with Node, and based on AutobahnJS both on the browser and Node side of thing. And I don't have much clue about the status of the routers you mention, sorry.

Comment: @Hedge - What's the reason you don't want to use Crossbar.io?

Comment: @gzost I might be able to answer for Hedge.  I'm putting together an application that uses Autobahn for pub/sub and RPCs.  It's working fine for me without Crossbar.  Given that it works without Crossbar, I have no reason to use Crossbar.  I've been reading on the Crossbar site that it provides pub/sub and RPC, but since I can do that with only Autobahn, I have a hard time understanding why I'd need Crossbar at all.  I've been trying to read about the decision between Autobahn vs Crossbar+Autobahn, but haven't found anything useful until I found this question.  What do you think?